# ¿Como abrir el link en nueva pestaña al hacer clic en una fila de una tabla html con jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

He utilizado jQuery para poner un enlace en una fila de una tabla de HTML. Ahora al hacer click en una fila el navegador abre mi enlace deseado gracias al siguiente código:

```
<tr class="clickable-row" data-href="Mi_enlace.php">

   <td> Lo que sea ... </td>
   ...

</tr>
```

Este es el jQuery que me ayuda a disparar el `href` "on click":

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".clickable-row").click(function() {
        window.document.location = $(this).data("href");
    });
});
```

Hasta ahí bien.

Ahora, **¿dónde he de incluir `target="_blank"` para que el enlace se abra en nueva pestaña en vez de abrirse en la misma?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.open('http://www.tuenlace.com');
```

Esto es lo que buscas creo, con poner la ruta te abre dicha ruta en una pestaña nueva.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @G3I0, me podrias especificar donde deberia incluir `window.open(...)` en mi codigo? Soy muy nuevo en jQuery y apreciaria muchisimo tu ayuda. Gracias !

Comment: donde haces el `window.document.location` @Lukas, quedaría algo así: `window.open($(this).data("href"));` si no funciona avisa ;)

Comment: Gracias, ahora si me funcionó ! Con `window.open($(this).data("href"));`

Answer (score 1):

Prueba añadiendo el atributo al final...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".clickable-row").click(function() {
        window.document.location = $(this).data("href").attr('target','_blank');
    });
});
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero asi on click no me abre el enlace y me mete este error: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).data(...).attr is not a function`

Comment: Tambien he intentado combiar  ' por  " y tampoco me va :D

Comment: `$(this).data("href")` debería devolver un string con el href por lo cual no puedes añadirle un atributo target